# Problems with twitter bootstrap scroll-spy

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

What is wrong with this code  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaa6S/).

I have done everything that the example said, tried `$('#navbar').scrollspy()` but still no success.

Please Explain my problem and point me to a solution.

Thank you!

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaa6S/2/)

Comment: really hard to read your code in fiddle

Comment: Yeah I know it is a form inside a table which is located in twitter bootstrap modal ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ScrollSpy object needs to be attached to the element which triggers **scroll** events.  In your current markup, that element would actually be the `<body>` not the `<table>` element.

Try removing the `data-spy="scroll" data-target=".nav"` attributes from the table, and adding them to the `<body>` instead.

Otherwise, if you want the `<table>` to originate **scroll** events, it needs to have a scroll bar, i.e. fixed `height` and `overflow: auto` (which is how the [Bootstrap Documentation Scrollspy example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy) does it).

---

#### Update

If you are placing the form in a modal, the element with the class `modal-body` is going to be the one which triggers scroll events.  Attach the Scrollspy object to it.

Comment: But I have a scroll bar... I have uploaded the coda that makes the modal and everything

Comment: OK worked but now the first two links are going crazy and it does not make the others active any ideas when I scroll it goes 1-2,2-1..... and like that until I hit bottom and then eventually it goes to 6 ..

Comment: Never Mind... it had fixed itself =D Thank You! Learned a lot!

Comment: Same problem for be.  Rotates between item 1 and 2 rapidly and then goes to the last item.  Not sure how you got it to fix itself. :)